# How do I avoid "Couldn't find a metric" when creating a metric alert in Bicep

Tags: azure, azure-bicep

I have the Bicep code below, to create an Azure SQL Database and a Metric Alert to inform me when the disk space utilisation hits 80%.

Deploying the Bicep when the database already exists works perfectly. However, **when the database and the alert both need to be created, the deployment fails** with the error "Couldn't find a metric named storage_percent".

Whenever our pipeline runs against an empty Resource Group, the deployment fails - but then our automatic retry succeeds.  (This is not an acceptable situation since this code is part of a larger deployment which takes around 10 minutes to complete.)

The Bicep code is as follows:

```bash
resource sqlServer 'Microsoft.Sql/servers@2021-02-01-preview' existing = {
  name: sqlServerName

  resource sqlDatabase 'databases' = {
    name: sqlDatabaseName
    properties: {
      // ...
    }
    // ...
  }
}

resource diskSpaceAlert 'Microsoft.Insights/metricAlerts@2018-03-01' = {
  name: '${sqlServer::sqlDatabase.name} Disk Space Low'
  location: 'global'
  properties: {
    description: '${sqlServer::sqlDatabase.name} database disk usage is above 80%'
    criteria: {
      'odata.type': 'Microsoft.Azure.Monitor.SingleResourceMultipleMetricCriteria'
      allOf: [
        {
          name: 'StoragePercentGt80'
          metricName: 'storage_percent'
          threshold: 80
          operator: 'GreaterThan'
          timeAggregation: 'Maximum'
          criterionType: 'StaticThresholdCriterion'
          skipMetricValidation: true  // Added in attempt to solve problem
        }
      ]
    }
    enabled: true
    evaluationFrequency: 'PT1H'
    scopes: [
      sqlServer::sqlDatabase.id
    ]
    severity: 2
    windowSize: 'PT1H'
    actions: [
      {
        actionGroupId: errorAlertingActionGroupId
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The raw error shown in the Azure Portal is:

```json
{
  "code": "DeploymentFailed",
  "target": "/subscriptions/.../resourceGroups/.../providers/Microsoft.Resources/deployments/...",
  "message": "At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-deployment-operations for usage details.",
  "details": [
    {
      "code": "BadRequest",
      "target": "/subscriptions/.../resourceGroups/.../providers/Microsoft.Resources/deployments/...",
      "message": "Couldn't find a metric named storage_percent. Make sure the name is correct. Activity ID: ..."
    }
  ]
}
```

Reading the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.insights/metricalerts?pivots=deployment-language-bicep), I hoped that adding `skipMetricValidation: true` would solve the problem, but this seems to have had no impact.

We are deploying in UK South.

Potentially of relevance, all our resources are accessible only from within Virtual Networks.

- The SQL Server has public access disabled, and Private endpoint connections configured.
- The Log Analytics workspace has an Azure monitor private link scope.  (I'm not sure if Metric Alerts utilise Log Anayltics.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most likely an issue in the SQL Database Resource Provider. We see this problem regularly, and only with the `storage_percent` metric.

The resource provider is reporting to the deployment engine that it has successfully completed and the engine is free to continue on with dependent deployments, even though some portions of the SQL DB under the hood are still being provisioned or configured. It creates the opportunity for this race condition when a dependent deployment tries to then work with the resource that is still pending in some way.

Manually adding the dependsOn, as the other answer suggests, won't help. Bicep will already create this under the hood when you use the resourceId, and the RP will still just say the dependsOn is satisfied.

One workaround is to manually create a delay, typically by running an ARM deployment script with a simple wait operation in a shell script, and making your alerts bicep depend on that deployment script. You could also make your alerts bicep depend on other things that you know take longer to buy yourself some time.

There is a [wait and retry feature that bicep is considering implementing](https://github.com/Azure/bicep/issues/1013#issuecomment-1667471590), where there are other examples of RPs not responding properly, including a comment I've linked to showing that there are other configurations on a sql server that also can spark similar dependency issues, not just metric alerts.

I'd also recommend submitting a ticket to Azure support if you have time.

Comment: I've currently implemented a delay by splitting my metric alerts into a separate Bicep deployment that runs later in my pipeline.  Thank you for the suggestions for implementing a delay within a single template.

Comment: I have added my  to the "wait and retry" feature request.

Comment: Nice, that's what we do as well. arm deployment scripts themselves are probably more unreliable than the resource providers.

Answer (score 0):

During the deployment process, it is likely that the database metrics will not be readily accessible for monitoring. In such a case, it might fail to recognize the `storage_percent` metric during validation. Redeploying the code after some time can be successful in this case.

After making a few changes to your code, deployment was successful even without adding the `skipMetricValidation` parameter to the metrics resource but with the same metric name `storage_percent`.

[image]

```bash
param sqlDatabaseName string = 'newdb'
param sqlServerName string = 'newserverj'
param resourceId string = '/subscriptions/subscriptionID/resourceGroups/resourcegroup/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/newserverj/databases/newdb'
resource sqlServer 'Microsoft.Sql/servers@2022-08-01-preview' existing = {
  name: sqlServerName
}
resource sqlDatabase 'Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases@2022-11-01-preview' existing = {
name: sqlDatabaseName
parent: sqlServer
}
resource diskSpaceAlert 'Microsoft.Insights/metricAlerts@2018-03-01' = {
  name: 'DiskSpaceLow'
  location: 'global'
  properties: {
    description: 'database disk usage is above 80%'
    criteria: {
      'odata.type': 'Microsoft.Azure.Monitor.SingleResourceMultipleMetricCriteria'
      allOf: [
        {
          name: 'StoragePercentGt80'
          metricName: 'storage_percent'
          threshold: 80
          operator: 'GreaterThan'
          timeAggregation: 'Maximum'
          criterionType: 'StaticThresholdCriterion'
        }
      ]
    }
    enabled: true
    evaluationFrequency: 'PT1H'
    scopes: [
      resourceId
    ]
    severity: 2
    windowSize: 'PT1H'
    actions: [
      {
        actionGroupId: '/subscriptions/subscriptionID/resourceGroups/resourcegroup/providers/microsoft.insights/actiongroups/actionadd'
      }
    ]
  }
  dependsOn: [
    sqlDatabase
  ]
}
```

***Deployment succeeded:***

[image]

[image]

*Note:* You can check the [supported metrics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/reference/supported-metrics/microsoft-sql-servers-databases-metrics) for SQL database in Azure.

Comment: Thanks Jahnavi.  You are right, my Bicep does always succeed on retry.  (This is done automatically by our deployment pipeline.)  However, this is one part of a much larger Bicep template and the retry takes 10 minutes.  Hence I'm keen to find a solution that will work on the first deployment attempt if possible.

Comment: The first deployment worked for me without any conflicts. Can you check your environment in the backend, clear the cache and try once. @Mike

Comment: Hi Jahnavi.  I shall continue to monitor this over the coming days, but at least 50% of the times our pipeline runs against an empty Resource Group, the first attempt fails due to this issue.  (Our Bicep template includes 4 Azure SQL Databases, each with a corresponding Metric Alert.)

Comment: All metric alerts are failing at a time? @Mike

Comment: Yes.  Typically (possibly every time) all 4 have failed together.  (And then all have succeeded on the second attempt.)

Comment: Are you executing the script in Azure cloud shell? @Mike

Comment: Did you check [troubleshooting issues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/troubleshooting/quickstart-troubleshoot-bicep-deployment?tabs=azure-cli) of bicep deployments? @Mike

Comment: we're using the Azure CLI from Azure Devops.

Comment: Can you upgrade the bicep using `az bicep upgrade` and try deployment again. And also in which region you are deploying into? @Mike

Comment: Deploying to UK South.  Have tried `az bicep upgrade`, but still got the same behaviour I'm afraid.  (Logs show `2023-08-24T10:55:54.2838941Z Installing Bicep CLI v0.20.4...` then `2023-08-24T10:55:54.2839350Z Successfully installed Bicep CLI to "/agent/_work/_temp/.azclitask/bin/bicep"`)

Comment: Was deployment successful? @Mike

Comment: On the second attempt, as ever!

Comment: This is not an issue with the bicep. Because I can successfully be able to run the script in the first attempt itself. There is something or the other is blocking the deployment in your environment. @Mike

Comment: Did you restart the Devops CLI and tried? @Mike

Comment: Hi Jahnavi.  Our pipeline runs on a ScaleSet, which spins up fresh build agents from an image, so I don't expect restarting the CLI would change anything.  However, if you're able to point me to how I could restart it then I would be happy to try.

I am seeing this problem very consistently (twice this morning when deploying our infrastructure to two different empty Resource Groups), so I'm intrigued that you are not experiencing the same.  We do have all our resources locked down within a Virtual Network, if that could make any difference...?

Comment: Yes, it does make a difference. In this case, when the deployment is consistent but not successful, you must examine the Devops pipeline logs as well as resource locks and permissions as your resources are locked in a virtual network. @Mike

Comment: Hi Jahnavi  I've scoured the logs, but there's nothing see beyond the raw error which I've added above.  And I would reiterate that the deployment always succeeds on retry, so it doesn't feel like a permissions issue...